# How to use ReactiveCocoa to subscribe to multiple selectors only once for each downloaded file

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, reactive-cocoa

I am new to ReactiveCocoa and trying to build an API Client using it. I want the RAC observer to fire once on each `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` delegate callback. as my code is now it will create an observer for each file that is downloaded and fire events for all previous files each time a file is downloaded. This method is called for every download of a file.

Is the correct way using RAC to dispose of the observer for each time its finished or to use a different part of RAC than subscribeNext with this pattern?

```
// In APIClient.swift

func urlSessionDownloadTask(method: httpMethod, url: String, acceptHeader: String, progress: NSProgress?, success: (url: NSURL) -> Void , failure: (error: APIError) -> ()) -> NSURLSessionTask? {
    let url = NSURL(string: url)
    var urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 50)
    urlRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue
    urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields![Constants.HTTPHeaderKeys.accept] = acceptHeader

    RACSignalSubscriptionNext(selector: Selector("URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:"), fromProtocol: NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate.self) { (racTuple) -> Void in
        let urlSession = racTuple.first as NSURLSession
        let downloadTask = racTuple.second as NSURLSessionDownloadTask
        let location = racTuple.third as NSURL
        println(location)
        println("Did finish downloading file, should only be called once per file")
        success(url: location)
    }
    RACSignalSubscriptionNext(selector:Selector("URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:") , fromProtocol: NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate.self) { (racTuple) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
             let totalBytesWritten = racTuple.fourth as NSNumber
             if let actualProgress = progress {
                 actualProgress.completedUnitCount = totalBytesWritten.longLongValue
             }
        })

    }
    let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: nil)
    task.resume()
}

//  just a convenice method to setup a next subscription
func RACSignalSubscriptionNext(#selector:Selector, fromProtocol: Protocol, subscribeNext: (racTuple: RACTuple) -> Void) {
        rac_signalForSelector(selector, fromProtocol:fromProtocol).subscribeNext { (anyObject) -> Void in
            if let racTuple = anyObject as? RACTuple {
                subscribeNext(racTuple: racTuple)
            } else {
                println("something wrong happened")
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason i am not using the completion handler downloadTaskWithRequest is that i want to subscribe to multiple `URLsessionDownloadDelegate` events